# image slideshow with dispatcher timer in windows store apps

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, slideshow

I want to make slideshow image with dispatcher timer in my windows store apps. But, i have a problem: if the image has reached the final image, the slideshow do not want to repeat the slideshow from the first image, but the second image directly. For example: I have 5 images and when it reaches the fifth picture, slideshows do not want a repeat of the first image, but the second image directly.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="sceneriesBtn" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Tapped="sceneriesBtn_Tapped" Height="242" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

And here my xaml.cs code:

```
public Home()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();          
        }

        DispatcherTimer playlistTimer1 = null;
        List<string> Images1 = new List<string>();

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageSource1();
        }
        private void ImageSource1()
        {
            Images1.Add("17-Ijen-Crater.jpg");
            Images1.Add("19-Ranu-kumbolo-Semeru.jpg");
            Images1.Add("30-Kelud-blitar.jpg");
            Images1.Add("31-sarangan_lake.jpg");
            Images1.Add("390-ranu_agung.jpg");
            playlistTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
            playlistTimer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            playlistTimer1.Tick += playlistTimer_Tick1;
            sceneriesBtn.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Sceneries/" + Images1[count1]));
            playlistTimer1.Start();
        }
        int count1 = 0;
        void playlistTimer_Tick1(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (Images1 != null)
            {
                if (count1 == Images1.Count - 1)
                    count1 = 0;
                if (count1 < Images1.Count)
                {
                    count1++;
                    ImageRotation1();
                }
            }
        }
        private void ImageRotation1()
        {
            sceneriesBtn.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Sceneries/" + Images1[count1].ToString()));
        }
  }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical flaw. In your code, the counter is changed twice, first from `Images1.Count - 1` to `0`, then incremented in the second if statement from `0` to `1`.

My fix

```
if (count1 < Images1.Count)
   count1++;

if (count1 >= Images1.Count)
      count1 = 0;

ImageRotation1();
```