# Image slideshow in Windows universal apps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I have been trying to create a Image Slideshow in my app. Been Searching forever for help and ended with this.

[image slideshow with dispatcher timer in windows store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003107/image-slideshow-with-dispatcher-timer-in-windows-store-apps)

I could understand the solution but what I didn't get is the URI Code. Where does the URI Point to? Is it a folder in the app files.

My app is called idk. And the pics are in a folder inside the App folder and is called Images.

Folder path
idk-->Images

What should my URI be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Uri can:

- Point to some asset in your application "ms-appx:///Sceneries/image.jpg" (if this is the path and name of your file)
- Or you can use an internet url like "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg"